# removeEventListener() not working for event added in HTML5 file

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to remove an event listener set on a button that I am setting up in a HTML5 file, but it seems it is not getting removed.

HTML5 file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="lab5v1js.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="loadPuzzle()">
<table>
    <tbody>
       ..........................
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="button" onmousedown="solve();" onmouseup="checkIfSolved()">SOLVE!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS file:

```
function checkIfSolved() {
    .......................
    //here it is ok, so remove handlers
    document.getElementById("button").removeEventListener("mousedown", solve);
    document.getElementById("button").removeEventListener("mousedown", checkIfSolved);

    alert("SOLVED!");
}
```

I have tried to print the result of the document.getElementById("button") before and after trying to remove the event listeners, but it seems there is no effect (they are not removed)...

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: removeEventListener does not work with the inline events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the method, not remove listener

```js
const solve = () => console.log('solve test');

function checkIfSolved() {

    //here it is ok, so remove handlers
    document.getElementById("button").onmousedown = undefined;

    alert("SOLVED!");
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
       ..........................
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="button" onmousedown="solve();" onmouseup="checkIfSolved()">SOLVE!</button>
</body>
```

If you want to use event listeners:

```js
const solve = () => console.log(`solve test - ${Date.now()}` );
function checkIfSolved() {

    document.querySelector("#button").removeEventListener('mousedown', solve);
    alert("SOLVED!");
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Add our click
  let btn = document.querySelector('#button');
  btn.addEventListener('mousedown', solve);
  btn.addEventListener('mouseup', checkIfSolved); 
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
       ..........................
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="button">SOLVE!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Happy coding !!